# Getting undefined when accessing json's value in $.each

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This is the each that traverses the response json object that I an receiving via ajax call.

```
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.pin + item.place);
    selected = response[i].pin.substr(0, zip.length);
    remain = response[i].pin.substr(zip.length);
    $(".zip-drop").append("<p class='zip-suggest'><span class='suggest-pin'><b>"+selected+"</b>"+remain+"</span><span class='suggest-place'>"+item.place+"</span></p>");
    return i < Object.keys(response).length - 1;
});
```

Everything is working fine, but in the console i'm getting `undefined` item.pin though the alert is producing the desired result. This `undefined` problem makes the ajax call stay for a long long time. I'm using a loader image and it stays forever once the ajax call is made.

Any solution for removing the `undefined` error. I can't understand why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but do you need all of those global variables? I'd be willing to bet that's at least part of the problem.

Comment: Those aren't globals and are declared in the event callback where the ajax call is created afterwards. Also `response` is what i'm getting in the success function of ajax.

Comment: `TypeError: response[i].pin is undefined` This is the error i'm getting. Same for item.pin

Comment: How many reference errors are you getting? One for every item in your collection? My guess is that not every item has a .pin property.

Comment: Every item has .pin property but last. That's why i'm limiting the loop to length -1

Comment: are keys numeric? is the object an array?

Comment: But you're not limiting your loop. If you want to limit it, make your check before you start referencing things using the next iteration of i in your .each body.

Comment: but to limit before you do stuff will return before executing further.

Comment: Can you add a sample response object to the question?

Comment: It is an object with just a last item that is not .pin

Comment: Yeah, isn't that what you just suggested you're trying to do? If all you want to do is avoid referencing a property that isn't there, then just check the object before referencing: if (response[i].pin) { // do something with response[i].pin }

Comment: I'm not doing quite that but cuz i know that .pin exists there till length - 1 so i'm trying to execute the loop length - 1 times, so that it never reaches there. I think the problem is in last statement, where i'm returning true or false.

Comment: I just changed the `-1` to `-2` and i dont have that error now. But i'm suspecting that if it can limit my last result to show up.

Comment: Just to be clear, you do or don't want to process the last item in the collection? If so, then just protect against referencing properties of an object that may not be defined. If not, then just check at the beginning of the .each body that you aren't on the last item in the collection.

Comment: you could also remove all that and put a check at the beginning... eg.`if(!response[i].pin) return false;` cheers :)

Comment: @Shanimal Thanks man! 
kinakuta - Yeah just got the thing. Well, Anybody post an answer so i can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also remove all that and put a check at the beginning... eg.

```
if(!response[i].pin) return false;
```

cheers :)